# how to reproduce this code using MongoDB $push & $inc operators?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I try to make this code work but using $inc to increment number of likes & $push to push the userId to the array usersLiked:

```
  Sauce.updateOne(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    {
      ...sauceObject,
      likes: req.body.like,
      dislikes: req.body.like,
      usersLiked: req.body.userId,
      usersDisliked: req.body.userId,
    }
  )
    .then(() => res.status(200).json({ message: "Sauce liked !" }))
    .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({ error }));
```

I tried this, but it returns an error:

```
db.Sauce.update(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
          $push: { usersLiked: req.body.userId },
          $inc: { likes: 1 },
        }
          .then(() => res.status(200).json({ message: "Sauce liked !" }))
          .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({ error }))
      );
```

Your help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Add function to your code because unless and until you don't call function it won't work and also use async function to increment number of likes